# The definition of closure.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Recently, i have seen the definition of closure as follows,
\begin{equation}
\text{cl}~C = \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}(C + \varepsilon B),
\end{equation}
where $B$ is Euclidean unit ball: $B=\{x \mid |x| \leq 1\}$.
I think it is right but i feel a little confused, because 
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \varepsilon B = \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}\varepsilon B = \{\boldsymbol{0}\}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, could i say
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{cl}~C &= \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0}(C + \varepsilon B)  \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}(C + \varepsilon B) \\
&= C + \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \varepsilon B \\
&= C + \{\boldsymbol{0}\}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
I think it is incorrect but i don't know why, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the definition of $B$?

Comment: $A+B$ means $\{a+b\mid a\in A, b\in B\}.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I am sorry for my carelessness and i have added the definition of $B$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Acctually we better ask what the hell is the definition $\lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}(\varepsilon B) $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the part where you made a mistake:
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}(C + \varepsilon B) = C + \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0} \varepsilon B
$$
The operation of taking limit here is *not* distributive with respect to Minkowski sum.

Comment: I got it, thanks. By the way, i have never seen a closure could be written in such a limit ($\lim(C+\varepsilon B)$). Can I write like this?

Comment: Yes, you can do that for a metric space. It essentially captures the fact that a closed set contains all of its limit points.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to analyze such a proof is by using a small example. Take $C=(-\infty,0)$, so the closure is $(-\infty,0]$. You say $\lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}((-\infty,0) + \varepsilon B) = (-\infty,0) + \lim_{\varepsilon \downarrow 0}(\varepsilon B)$, which does not seem right.

Answer (score 1):

Writing an intersection $\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}^\infty A_\varepsilon$ of sets satisfying $A_x \subset A_y$ for $x<y$ as a *limit* is misleading to say the least. In this case it lead you to the false believe that this intersection is compatible with (Minkowski) sums.

That is, in general:
$$
\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} (A_\varepsilon+B_\varepsilon) \color{red}\neq \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} A_\varepsilon + \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} B_\varepsilon.
$$

---

Consider the example where $C = (0,1)\subset \Bbb R$ and $B=[-1,1]$ is the closed unit ball. Note that
$$
\bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} (C+\varepsilon B) = \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} (-\varepsilon, 1+\varepsilon) = [0,1] = \operatorname{cl}\,(0,1)
$$
while
$$
C + \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} \varepsilon B = C + \{0\} = C = (0,1) \color{red}\neq \operatorname{cl}\,(0,1).
$$

Comment: Thanks, i find that the $limit$ brings some misleading.

Comment: Well, you can describe it as a kind of limit and this actually can be made more precise, but it behaves very different from the kind of point-wise limits you know from calculus. – Be careful when importing intuitions from other subjects that have related notations!